Smart Contract Works in Remix and Foundry, but Fails After Deployment to Local Chain or Sepolia
I've developed a smart contract called BudgetSystem that works perfectly in the Remix IDE and has been tested on Foundry. However, after deploying the contract using Anvil on my local chain or the Sepolia network, it does not function properly. I'm encountering issues with basic functions, such as retrieving the budget balance. Specifically, when I use cast call to get the total budget of the contract after deployment, it returns an empty string 0x.
Screenshots:


Contract Code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {console} from "forge-std/console.sol";
import {Ownable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract BudgetSystem is Ownable {
    // ERRORS
    error BudgetSystem__ExceededAmount();
    error BudgetSystem__DepartmentDoesNotExist();
    error BudgetSystem__ExceedsAllocatedBudget();
    error BudgetSystem__ExceedsRequestedFunds();
    error BudgetSystem__AmountMustBeMoreThanZero();

    // STATE VARIABLES
    uint256 public totalBudget;

    struct Department {
        uint256 allocatedBudget;
        uint256 requestedFunds;
        uint256 spentFunds;
        bool exists;
    }

    mapping(address => Department) public departments;

    // EVENTS
    event BudgetAllocated(address indexed department, uint256 amount);
    event FundsRequested(address indexed department, uint256 amount);
    event FundsReleased(address indexed department, uint256 amount);

    // Modifiers
    modifier nonZero(uint256 amount) {
        if(amount <= 0){
            revert  BudgetSystem__AmountMustBeMoreThanZero();
        }
        _;
    }

    constructor(uint256 _totalBudget) Ownable(msg.sender) payable {
        totalBudget = _totalBudget;
    }

    function allocateBudget(address departmentAddress, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner nonZero(amount) {
        if (amount > totalBudget) {
            revert BudgetSystem__ExceededAmount();
        }

        departments[departmentAddress].allocatedBudget += amount;
        departments[departmentAddress].exists = true;
        totalBudget -= amount;

        emit BudgetAllocated(departmentAddress, amount);
    }

    function requestFunds(uint256 amount) public nonZero(amount) {
        Department storage dept = departments[msg.sender];
        
        if(!dept.exists){
            revert BudgetSystem__DepartmentDoesNotExist();
        }

        if(amount > dept.allocatedBudget - dept.spentFunds){
            revert BudgetSystem__ExceedsAllocatedBudget();
        }

        dept.requestedFunds += amount;
        emit FundsRequested(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function releaseFunds(address payable departmentAddress, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner nonZero(amount) {
        Department storage dept = departments[departmentAddress];

        if(dept.requestedFunds < amount){
            revert BudgetSystem__ExceedsRequestedFunds();
        }
        
        dept.spentFunds += amount;
        dept.requestedFunds -= amount;
        departmentAddress.transfer(amount);  

        emit FundsReleased(departmentAddress, amount);
    }

    ///////////////////////
    // GETTER FUNCTIONS /// 
    ///////////////////////

    function getRemainingBudget(address departmentAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        Department storage dept = departments[departmentAddress];
        return dept.allocatedBudget - dept.spentFunds;
    }

    function getAllocatedBudget(address departmentAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        Department storage dept = departments[departmentAddress];
        return dept.allocatedBudget;
    }

    function getRequestFunds(address departmentAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        Department storage dept = departments[departmentAddress];
        return dept.requestedFunds;
    }

    function getSpentFunds(address departmentAddress) external view returns (uint256) {
        Department storage dept = departments[departmentAddress];
        return dept.spentFunds;
    }

    function getBudgetContractBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getTotalBudget() external view returns (uint256) {
        return totalBudget;
    }
}

Deployment Code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Script, console} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {BudgetSystem} from "../src/budgetSystem.sol";

contract DeployBudgetSystem is Script {
    uint256 private constant TOTAL_BUDGET = 100 ether; 

    function run() external {
        vm.startBroadcast();
        BudgetSystem budgetSystem = new BudgetSystem(TOTAL_BUDGET);
        console.log("BudgetSystem deployed at:", address(budgetSystem));
        console.log("Total budget after deployment:", budgetSystem.getTotalBudget());
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}

What could be causing this? Both cast send and cast call are not working properly any function i use cast call it returns an empty string.
I'm using Forge for deployment.
The network I deployed to is either a local Anvil chain or the Sepolia network.

Hi Joewi, as a new contributor, I'll give you some tips on this question, and I'll respond with a possible solution below. Typically, you'll want to minimize your question as much as possible. This is what I call a "debug me" question, which is "low effort" on your end but high effort on the helpers end. I'd try to minimize your question as much as possible to maximize your chance of answer in the future. Please read this for asking questions in the future.
https://github.com/Cyfrin/foundry-full-course-cu/blob/main/how-to-ask-a-question.md

Thank you Patrick the reason why i showed my whole code is because all the responses have gotten I've tried it and it did not work so i provided the full code maybe if someone runs it on his computer if we still get the same issue i just made a new file and recopied the code and ran it still got the same 0x error although when deployed to a sepolia chain and i try to "getTotalBudget()" using cast call i actually get this error "contract 0x56ca8a3a52d95838c0f133e071350198af3098ab does not have any code"

It's most likely you're forgetting the rpc-url flag.
For anvil:
cast call 0x0575420efaGbE1AD7E3d6Fe36dccd4247FBF97 "getTotalBudget()" --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:8545

Sepolia:
cast call 0x0575420efaGbE1AD7E3d6Fe36dccd4247FBF97 "getTotalBudget()" --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL

Note
This is a "debug me" style question, which is very difficult for people to answer, and not very helpful to other people who find this post. When posting here, try your best to minimize your question so that:

You increase your chances of getting answered
You help other people who have similar questions

Your question as currently written is very specific to you, and it's unlikely that others would gain value from it.

Okay guys so i decided to re-run my code in a new environment and I was still getting error when interacting with my local chain (ANVIL) and sepolia network but then I redeployed my contract on the sepolia network again but this time using --broadcast
forge script script/DeployBudgetSystem.s.sol --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast

and after that i called the cast call function and go this output
cast call 0x56Ca8a3a52d95838C0F133e071350198AF3098AB "getTotalBudget()(uint256)" --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY
100000000000000000000 [1e20]

So, everything is functioning correctly on the Sepolia network now! Thanks
